# Quick Question about summing $(n^{\alpha}_{\ \ \alpha})^{2}$

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

This is a pretty dumb question, but regardless:

Suppose $n$ is a rank-2 tensor with components $n_{\alpha \beta}$, where $\alpha$ runs from $1$ to $2$.

How would I evaluate the quantity $(n^{\alpha}_{\ \ \alpha})^{2}$? (I'm using the Einstein Summation convention)

There are two ways as far as I can see:

WAY $1$: $\ \ \ \ (n^{\alpha}_{\ \ \alpha})^{2} = (n^{1}_{\ \ 1}+n^{2}_{\ \ 2})^{2} = \ .....$

WAY $2$: $\ \ \ \ (n^{\alpha}_{\ \ \alpha})^{2} = (n^{1}_{\ \ 1})^{2}+(n^{2}_{\ \ 2})^{2} = \ .....$

I am leaning towards WAY $1$ for sure, but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: Seems a bit ambiguous to me. Can you provide any context for how this came up?

Comment: There's a paper by MacCallum "Cosmological models from a geometric point of view", this term comes up in Equation (84) - it's a general relativistic equation that falls out of the Einstein Field Equations.

Comment: And just because the notation has a logical interpretation, doesn't mean the person who wrote it was thinking logically at the time... Fundamentally, the trace of a tensor is independent of the basis, so you can write it in summation convention/abstract index notation, but the sum of the squares of the diagonal elements is not invariant, so you can't. So I think it *should* be the first one.

Answer (score 1):

In the Einstein convention, implicit sums occur over *pairs* of indices; so using this notation to mean $\sum_\alpha n^\alpha_\alpha n^\alpha_\alpha$ would be quite sloppy. It's made even less likely (as observed by Chappers in the comments) by the fact that this expression is not invariant under change of basis.

It's hard to be certain without more context (couldn't get hold of the paper quickly), but it seems overwhelmingly likely that it's intended to be interpreted as the invariant quantity $|n|^4 = (\sum_\alpha n^\alpha_\alpha)^2$.